# mypy Incompatible return value type for numeric types

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-3.10

consider this example

```
from typing import TypeVar

Even = TypeVar("Even",bound=int)
Odd  = TypeVar("Odd",bound=int)


def make_even(n:int) -> Even:
    return n*2
    
def make_odd(n:int) -> Odd:
    return n*2+1

def make_both(n:int) -> tuple[Even,Odd]:
    return make_even(n), make_odd(n)

help(make_both)
```

its output is nice and all, exactly like I want it

```
Help on function make_both in module __main__:

make_both(n: int) -> tuple[~Even, ~Odd]
```

but mypy doesn't like it.

```
test5.py:8: error: Incompatible return value type (got "int", expected "Even")
test5.py:11: error: Incompatible return value type (got "int", expected "Odd")
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

So my question is how to please mypy and still keep the nice output from help? beside `#type: ignore` I suppose

Comment: I think there some confusion here about what [`TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) is. Your use here doesn't make any sense to me. Maybe you're mixing it up with [`NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NewType)? It would help if you explained what your goal is. Are you trying two make to distinct types that behave like `int` but can't be accidentally assigned to one another?

Comment: I use TypeVar to get the desired output, even using NewType I got the same problem and the output from help is less desirable to me

Comment: I want to express in the signature the result of the function, that this return some ints with some special characteristic, in the sample that the ints are even or odd, or that they are say fibonacci numbers or whatever else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this pass type checking, use `NewType` instead:

```py
from typing import NewType

Even = NewType('Even', int)
Odd  = NewType('Odd', int)


def make_even(n: int) -> Even:
    return Even(n*2)
    
def make_odd(n : int) -> Odd:
    return Odd(n*2 + 1)

def make_both(n: int) -> tuple[Even, Odd]:
    return make_even(n), make_odd(n)
```

But now `help` prints fully qualified names (`__main__.Even` in interpreter). To resolve this, you can use string literals or `annotations` future:

```py
...

def make_both(n: int) -> 'tuple[Even, Odd]':
    return make_even(n), make_odd(n)
```

or

```py
from __future__ import annotations
...

def make_both(n: int) -> tuple[Even, Odd]:
    return make_even(n), make_odd(n)
```

In first case `help` output is

```
Help on function make_both in module __main__:

make_both(n: int) -> 'tuple[Even, Odd]'
```

in second

```
Help on function make_both in module __main__:

make_both(n: 'int') -> 'tuple[Even, Odd]'
```

Comment: In the end, because this of calling Even on things at runtime that just do nothing doesn't feel right to me, I went with a variation of this, I discarded the NewType and use instead `Even:TypeAlias = int` and in the signature put it as a string

Comment: `TypeAlias` is suitable too. The difference is in type checking strictness: if you have some method that uses `Even` as argument, `TypeAlias` will let you pass `3`, while `NewType` will require you to pass `Even(3)` and reject integers that are not marked as `Even` manually.

Comment: The most strict solution will be new `int` subclass `Even` with validation in `__new__` - `mypy` will not disallow `Even(3)`, but runtime will fail.

Comment: sure, but I will not make the program worse at run time just to please mypy, at run time I can, like you said, check if necessary, otherwise this is more for documentation